# difference between current timestamp and last modified timestamp of an S3 file using Glue python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, time, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Using python in AWS glue, I need to check if the files in an s3 location was modified in last 2 hours and based on that I have to run a job. I have tried few methods but in vain. Let me know if anyone would be able to help with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [job bookmark feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) for this use-case. This keeps track of the last modified timestamp of files and only processes those that have not been processed yet.